# Reverse Geocoding in Javascript with Google Maps returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geocoding

I've got a jsfiddle here:

[Reverse Geocoding test](http://jsfiddle.net/fngoxf8o/6/)

It's designed to get the user's location in two ways:

- Allowing the user to zoom and pan to their chosen location and click the map to set the location in the box below the map. This first part works great.
- Using the HTML5 Position functionality. This is in two parts:

1) Browser is queried by the Javascript, and returns coordinates. This part also works fine.

2) The returned coordinates are passed to the Google Geocoder to get the address. This part fails with `ZERO_RESULTS`.

I'm not sure why it's not getting results. If you might be able to help me puzzle this out I'll much appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in your question itself, not just a link to an external site such as jsfiddle.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that next time, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a string into `google.maps.LatLng` instead of the lat and long separately:

```
var newLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fngoxf8o/7/) with my changes.

Comment: It's always something completely idiotic. I guess that's how we learn :)